# Average a range of values based on a roster

Tags: arrays, excel, formula

I've checked other posts similar but I did not see a good way to do this. I have a roster and a list of tickets. I'm trying to get the average value of a column for anyone on the roster. The average should be 2.96 days. So far this is the formula I have:

```
AVERAGEIFS(IncidentTable[End to End],IncidentTable[Assigned to],Roster[Names],IncidentTable[Opened],">="&$C$4,IncidentTable[Opened],"<="&$C$5)
```

which works great and does what I expect but I get this output:

```
3.149498457
3.263309028
3.082010851
3.797272377
3.332628577
1.963191303
4.16268777
3.642668237
2.858988889
5.070617511
0.417111626
1.887283353
5.554509499
2.454277869
5.616894719
3.014369457
3.810059428
14.63350694
2.644313352
```

Which makes sense because I'm giving it more than one input for it do work off of. The question I have is how can I make it average this into a singular data point?

I thought I could do this

```
average(AVERAGEIFS(IncidentTable[End to End],IncidentTable[Assigned to],Roster[Names],IncidentTable[Opened],">="&$C$4,IncidentTable[Opened],"<="&$C$5))
```

but that gives me the average of the average and didn't work how I intended it to. Hopefully I was clear. Thank you all in advanced.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

do SUMIFS and COUNTIFS:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(SUMIFS(IncidentTable[End to End],IncidentTable[Assigned to],Roster[Names],IncidentTable[Opened],">="&$C$4,IncidentTable[Opened],"<="&$C$5))/SUMPRODUCT(COUNTIFS(IncidentTable[End to End],IncidentTable[Assigned to],Roster[Names],IncidentTable[Opened],">="&$C$4,IncidentTable[Opened],"<="&$C$5))
```